# No recibo valores $_POST de mi html

Tags: php

Tengo un formulario, donde tengo una entrada sola, y un boton.

```
<form role="form" method="post">
       <div class="form-group mb-none">
         <div class="input-group">
           <input placeholder="E-mail" type="text" name="entrada" class="form-control input-lg">
           <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button name="operar" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" >Activar! </button>
           </span>
         </div>
       </div>           
     </form>
```

y el codigo php tengo lo siguiente:

```
<?php 
  if (!empty($_POST['operar'])){
      if (strlen($_POST['entrada']) > 9){  //valida que el campo no este vacio y que sea mayor de 9
        echo "biennnnn";
      }else{
      ?>     
      <div class="alert alert-success">
         <p class="m-none text-semibold h6">
          Listo! Tu cuenta se encuentra activa nuevamente.                                                        </p>
      </div>

      <?php 
          }
         }        

      ?>
```

Esta todo en un mismo archivo. Presiono el boton y no pasa nada, se queda todo igual. Yo lo que quiero es que, en un principio me funcione el primer echo: **echo "biennnnn";**

Comment: Envías los datos directo con el formulario (html5 puro) o con javascript?

Comment: es solo html. Igualmente el problema esta que no entra en la condicion IF. Porque no me imprime nada.

Comment: Intenta poner action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" en el form y al button un type="submit"

Comment: Me da que tu problema es que estas buscando el valor de 'operar'  y este es el nombre del botón no de un campo del formulario.

Comment: Ahora mismo tu `<form>` no hace nada. Tienes un botón, que a no ser que le tengas asignado un evento de **Javascript** no te va a hacer absolutamente nada al hacer **click**. Para que un formulario solamente con **HTML** funcione necesitas que la etiqueta `<form>` tenga un atributo `action` (para que sepa lo que tiene que hacer cuando se envíe. Puede ser una **URL** o una llamada a una función) y que exista dentro del `<form>` un `<button type="submit">` de esa manera el botón sabrá que tiene que llamar al `action` del `<form>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cosas que veo que están mal y deberías cambiar:

1. En tu etiqueta `form` no tienes un `action`, aunque vaya al mismo archivo deberías indicarlo de esta forma:

   ```
   <form role="form" method="post" action="">
   ```

   Ó

   ```
   <form role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
   ```
2. Tu boton deberia ser un `<input type="submit"` en vez de `<button>` y el texto *Activar* para que esté dentro del botón debe estar en el atributo `value`

   ```
   <input type="submit" name="operar" value="Activar!" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" >
   ```
3. Por último, en tu **PHP**, para que te renozca el boton pulsado, utiliza `isset()` en vez de `empty()` para saber si está definida.

   ```
   if (!isset($_POST['operar'])){
   ```

Mas información de la función [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 0):

Si haces un var_dump de el post completo, te darás cuenta que de hecho `$_POST['operar']` es una cadena de length 0, por lo tanto no cumple tu primera condición `if (!empty($_POST['operar']))`

Puedes comprobarlo con
        `var_dump($_POST)`

Para evaluar el valor de elemento `<button>` necesitas agregar el atributo `value` . Si haces la prueba como en la linea a continuación, tu código si funcionará.

`<button name="operar" value="mi-valor" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" >Activar! </button>`

No sé si lo que deseas es confirmar si hubo un post o no, o si viene con los valores vacíos, puesto que el value del button es predeterminado por vos, entonces sería constante. Para evaluar si hubo post o no yo usaría

`if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')`

porque `if (!empty($_POST))` puede fallar en ciertos casos (ejemplo: `check boxes` y `button` sin `name`)